# Multi language jasper report using grails

Tags: java, grails, jasper-reports

How to create multi language Jasper report using Grails?

I am using Jasper plugin to generate report. I tried using `${R.Resource}` but I am unable to track exact path where `.property` file should be placed.

Comment: My first impression would be it should be in resource directory (main directory of your application). This thread ( http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/541062/how-add-properties-files-internationalization ) seems to point exact same thing, but with a fix to remove absolute path from config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

editing the report, in the xml you can specify the resouce boundle containing the .properties. To do that you must put in the attribute `resourceBundle` of the `jasperReport` tag the location of your `.property` file/s.
for example, if they are placed under the packege `org.mycomp.gui` your xml should look like:

```
 <jasperReport xlsns......   resourceBundle="org/mycomp/gui ......>
```

in that package you will have for instance `gui.properties`, `gui_en.properties` and so on

hope this help